# Best book to learn Sharepoint Administration (MOSS)?

Tags: sharepoint

What is the best available book for learning Sharepoint administration? Would prefer a cover-to-cover read rather than a reference book, but would take a good reference over a bad guide any day.

Comment: Was MOSS thrown in your lap also?

Answer (score 7):

If you ask me, the BEST books about SharePoint administration are these two, both written by [Bill English](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/search-handle-url/search-type=ss&index=books&field-author=Bill%20English):

1. [Microsoft® Office SharePoint® Server 2007 Administrator's Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735622825)
2. [Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Best Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625387)

Answer (score 2):

Toni's two recommendations are excellent, and I would also strongly recommend [Inside SharePoint 2007 Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584506016) by Todd Klindt and Shane Young.  Very readable and walks you through everything you need to know.

Also (don't laugh at me here), the content up on the [TechNet SharePoint TechCenter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/default.aspx) is very well written and readable (not to mention free!)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend Mastering Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 by C.A. Callahan.  Even though this is a WSS focused book - as an admin, I spend a great deal of time on that part of the application - and this is a great reference tool - one you can grab and look up something and then go back to whatever else you were up to.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make a recommendation (although I can't help repeating the earlier suggestion of the Best Practices book *but only if you have already worked with MOSS for at least 6 months as otherwise imo it's too much too soon*), here's a link to my list of all SharePoint books out there and about to be out there.

http://wssv3faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v3%20WSS%20FAQ/V%20Books.aspx

The pure Admin books are in section A, but Best Practices for instance isn't there but in section D (General), so check out at least that section too.